# how to handle crashed MYISAM db table?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MYSQL MYISAM.  during some update operation the query hanged and had to be killed.
Table './mydb/mytable' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
do I have no choice but to drop the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [myisamchk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk-repair-options.html) to repair the table.

First try this:

```
myisamchk -r -q table
```

And if that fails, try this: (**make sure you backup first!**)

```
myisamchk -r table
```